# How to calculate a moving average in my dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
datetime          year  month  day hour event impression
31/12/2017 11:20  2017  12     31  11   A1    22.30
31/12/2017 11:55  2017  12     31  11   A2    25.00
31/12/2017 12:05  2017  12     31  12   B1    21.15
31/12/2017 12:20  2017  12     31  12   C3    22.45
01/01/2018 10:00  2018  1      1   10   A3    24.35
01/01/2018 10:30  2018  1      1   10   A1    23.00
01/01/2018 11:15  2018  1      1   11   C3    22.61
```

I need to calculate an average `impression` using a slicing window of 2 hours. In other words, for each row of a DataFrame `df`, I want to create a new field `impression_last2hours`. This field should contain an average of `impression` for the last 2 hours (considering the change of year, month and day).

If the data for the last 2 hours is not available, then the value of should be equal to `impression_last2hours`. If at least 1 value of `impression` is available for the last 2 hours, then `impression_last2hours` should be calculate using available values.

Which functions can I use to do this task? Should I use a moving average?

Comment: Check dupe, if still problem, let me know.

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks. If I use this approach `df['new_col'] = data['column'].rolling(2).mean()`, how do I specify the units of a rolling window? I think that `rolling` takes last 2 **rows**. However in my case I may have dropouts, e.g. `31-12-2017 12:50` and the next row  `31-12-2017 15:30`. So, `rolling` would give a wrong answer for `31-12-2017 15:30`.

Comment: Create datetimeIndex and then use `df['new_col'] = data['column'].rolling('2H').mean()`

Comment: @jezrael: To create a datetime index, the solution is `df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df["datetime"])`? and then `df["impression_last2hours"] = data["impression
"].rolling("2H").mean()`. Is it what you suggest?